# How Can i validate the first character of a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to get the script to find the very first character '' backslash  and validate if that's the first character of a script otherwise it should not run.

my file is like **Test.txt** (have lot of starting spaced lines intentionally):

```
\c

select * from x;
```

I came up with this and it works:

```
cut -c -1 test.txt | grep -w '\\'
```

However if i changed a file a bit suppose like:

```
select * from x;

\c
```

it still shows file contains '\' but i want this to fail because i always want the first character to be '\' no matter which line i start.

I have tried using head/cut but not able to validate.Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Why searching the whole file for this character, if you only want to know whether it is the first one? Do it the other way round: Extract the first character and test whether it is a backslash. Or extract the first line using the `head` command and use pattern matching to see whether this line starts with a backslash.

Comment: I was literally trying that for the past day but it wasn't passing all the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses regex to check if the 1st encountered line contains starts with . If 1st encountered line does not start with \ it exits.

```
backslash_pat='^\\'
num_lett_pat='[0-9a-Z*]'

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $backslash_pat ]]
    then
            echo "$line"
            exit
    elif [[ $line =~ $num_lett_pat ]]
    then
            exit
    fi
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the fitst character is a `\` (I understand this is what you want) using `dd`

```
if [[ $(dd if=test.txt count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null| xxd -c1 -ps) == 5c ]]
then
    echo 'found'
fi
```

This works for binary file (i.e. not composed of lines).

Check `man dd` and `man xxd` to understand the command line options used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately i don't have xxd and i wont be able to install as it is production environment but ill definitely check it out!

Comment: Try similar `od` or `hexdump`

Comment: I don't see why it is necessary to go to hex. The backslash is a printable character - you can test it literally. Just be careful with quoting. Actually, if you would drop the detour to hex, I would upvote your question, because the basic approach implements directly what the OP wanted to have.